# Ansible: ansible.builtin.expect runs into timout

Tags: ansible

I try to pass on the username and password to the script with a task using **ansible.builtin.expect:** but it runs into a timeout.

**TASK:**

```
- name: Set superuser password
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: /bin/bash -c ". /opt/netbox/venv/bin/activate && python3 /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py changepassword {{ username }}"
    responses:
      "Password:": "{{ password\n}}"
      "Password (again):": "{{ password\n}}"
  vars:
    username: YYYYYYYYYY
    password: XXXXXXXXXXX
  become: yes
  register: changepassword_output
  changed_when: "'Password changed successfully for user' in changepassword_output.stdout"
```

**ERROR:**

```
fatal: [xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/bin/bash -c \". /opt/netbox/venv/bin/activate && python3 /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py changepassword YYYYYYYYYY\"", "delta": "0:00:32.086416", "end": "2023-05-02 18:36:43.252446", "msg": "command exceeded timeout", "rc": null, "start": "2023-05-02 18:36:11.166030", "stdout": "Changing password for user 'YYYYYYYYYY'\r\nPassword: \r\nPassword (again): ", "stdout_lines": ["Changing password for user 'YYYYYYYYYY'", "Password: ", "Password (again): "]}
```

**If executed manually: **

```
USER@SERVER:~$ . /opt/netbox/venv/bin/activate && python3 /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py changepassword YYYYYYYYYY
Changing password for user 'YYYYYYYYYY'
Password: <XXXXXXXXXXX [Typed manually]>
Password (again): <XXXXXXXXXXX [Typed manually]>
Password changed successfully for user 'YYYYYYYYYY'
```

**I expect that**

```
responses:
      "Password:": "{{ password\n}}"
      "Password (again):": "{{ password\n}}"
```

Would properly react to the request of manage.py by parsing the password.

[https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-expect-module](https://stackoverflow.com)

also tried this option as in the Example, but no luck.

```
    responses:
      Question:
        - response1
        - response2
        - response3
```

Comment: Just a quick guess, this may not be your only problem, but "{{ password\n }}" will be looking for a var literally named that. Try "{{ password }}\n"" for the password followed by a newline. That may be why it's timing out, you're effectively never hitting enter. (You may not need to say \n at all, I think it's implied)

Comment: @MattBlaha
Soooo, turns out I never used "{{ password\n}}" but had a try without \n which produced a similar issue. I foolishly placed the /n at the wrong spot when wrote my question. 
But I found the Problem and write it as a Answer on this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
(?i)Password: "{{ password }}"
(?i)Password (again): "{{ password }}"
```

Look in the [notes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-expect-module) would have helped:
The question, or key, under responses is a python regex match. Case insensitive searches are indicated with a prefix of ?i.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in the question, is that, we need to escape the parenthesis, as it is a special character in [python regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

```
- name: Set superuser password
  ansible.builtin.expect:
    command: /bin/bash -c ". /opt/netbox/venv/bin/activate && python3 /opt/netbox/netbox/manage.py changepassword {{ username }}"
    responses:
      "Password:": "{{ password\n }}"
      "Password \\(again\\):": "{{ password\n }}"
  vars:
    username: YYYYYYYYYY
    password: XXXXXXXXXXX
  become: yes
  register: changepassword_output
  changed_when: "'Password changed successfully for user' in changepassword_output.stdout"
```

@MuffinSlayer your answer is working, because, the first string `(?i)Password` is matching for both lines

```
Password: <XXXXXXXXXXX [Typed manually]>
Password (again): <XXXXXXXXXXX [Typed manually]>
```